# How can I find linear dependency's , when one (or more) coefficients are fixed?

Tags: linear-algebra

There are two ways to find integers a,b,c , such that ax^2+bx+c is approximately 0 , with PARI/GP

The first possibility is lindep([x^2,x,1],p) , where p is optional for the accuracy and the other is

qflll([1,0,0;0,1,0;0,0,1;10^6*x^2,10^6*x,10^6]) , where 10^6 is only an example number determining the accuracy again.

> But how can I find, for example integers a,b such that x^2+ax+b is approximately 0 ?

In other words, how can I fix one or more coefficients ?

Comment: You'll probably get more responses if you give some context, like what language are you using? 

There are infinite triples (a,b,c) and pairs (a,b) that satisfy the first and second equations. The former gives you a plane of solutions while the latter gives a line. You "fix the coefficients" by simply treating them as constants instead of variables.

Comment: @willem PARI/GP is a high-precision-calculator. It allows to find integers a,b,c such that ax^2+bx+c is approximately 0 for a given real number x. But I want to get integers a,b , such that x^2+ax+b is approximately 0. Hence in the tripel (a,b,c) returned by PARI/GP my goal is to fix a=1 , but I do not know how this works. And note that we do not get a line or plane because the coefficients must be integers. What we get, is a lattice.

Comment: And finally, The expression x^2+ax+b should be APPROXIMATELY 0, not exactly 0 , and x is an arbitary given real number.

Comment: There are infinitely many such pairs (a,b), so you should think carefully about what it is exactly that you are looking for. If you are interested in generating a list of all possible solutions, how should such a list be ranked, and which pair should be at the top of it?

I would recommend formulating this as an optimization problem, and thinking carefully about what specifications you would like the solution to take. For example, you might want the smallest 1-norm solution |a|+|b| that satisfies |x^2+ax+b| < epsilon for some tolerance epsilon.